# How can I rigorously justify introducing a new variable into a sentence?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

I was thinking about a problem I saw on stack exchange today about linear maps, in which we were given that for some linear map, $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, we have that $\text{Im}(T) \cap \text{Ker}(T) = \{0\}$. I.e. the intersection of the kernel and image of the linear map is the contains the zero vector only. **I want to clarify whether my equivalence $(*)$ below is correct, and if it is, how is it formally justified (and does my proposed 'proof' work?)**

Based on the posed question, we deduce the following:

$$x = 0 \iff x \in \text{Im}(T) \cap \text{Ker}(T)$$

Simply from the given assumption that $\text{Im}(T) \cap \text{Ker}(T) = \{0\}$. Now using the definitions of the kernel and image, we have the following equivalence: $$x \in \text{Im}(T) \cap \text{Ker}(T) \iff \exists a (x=T(a)) \land T(x) = 0$$

I am now interested in the RHS. Is the following equivalence true?:$$\exists a (x=T(a)) \land T(x) = 0 \iff \exists a(T(T(a) = 0)\tag{*}$$

To me the $\implies$ is obvious. We may use existential instantiation to introduce a new object/symbol $a$, and say $x=T(a)$. Then since $T(x)=0$, then $T(T(a)) = 0$. Since $T(T(a))=0$ is true for some element in our domain of discourse (the vectors), then by existential instantiation, we may conclude $\exists a(T(T(a) = 0)$.

My main problem comes when I try to prove the $\impliedby$ direction. When we start with $\exists a(T(T(a) = 0)$, I think we can use existential instantiation to deduce $T(T(a))=0$ for some $a$. **Here is where I have the main difficulty.** To me, it seems 'obvious' that I can simply 'define' $x=T(a)$. Then now $x$ is an object in our domain of discourse, and we can also say $T(x)=0$, since $T(a)$. Hence it seems like I have shown both $\exists a (x=T(a))$ and $T(x) = 0$.

But something here feels wrong; Mainly because I don't know exactly what logical step I am invoking when I 'define' my new symbol/variable $x$. I am a bit uncomfortable with the introduction of $x$, and specifically how $x$ remains unquantified in the statement. It seems like perhaps the precise meaning of the statements is different somehow, but I can't put my finger on it.

---

I tried reading the answer here: [Formal logic behind defining variables in a proof (not E.I. or U.G, etc.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150857/formal-logic-behind-defining-variables-in-a-proof-not-e-i-or-u-g-etc), but I am not sure I quite followed. My understanding of formal logic is very basic, and generally my only experience is proving things from 'regular' maths like analysis/algebra. If this is perhaps a topic that requires more in-depth knowledge that I currently have, I would like to know that too.